# Matching generic type within list entry but not across list entries

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a list of function references and their parameters:

```js
type WorkItem<Param, Result> = { fn: (param: Param) => Promise<Result>; param: Param}
type WorkItems<Param, Result> = WorkItem<Param, Result>[];
```

I want the type checking to enforce that the provided parameters match the provided function reference.

For example, I did hope the following to pass type checking:

```js
async function first(param: string) {
    return param
}

async function second(param: number) {
    return param
}

async function execute<Param, Result>(workItems: WorkItems<Param, Result>){
    return Promise.all(workItems.map((workItem) => workItem.fn(workItem.param)));
}

await execute([
    { fn: first; param: 'test' },
    { fn: second; param: 123 }, 
]) // type checking will raise warnings here that not all types match
```

Can I allow any type for the list entries while still maintaining the consistency check that the params match the function params?

Comment: • Please [edit] to remove typos; I'd suggest you check everything in an IDE and fix any syntax errors you encounter. • Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjoj1N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You could rewrite your execute type like that and it will maybe work as intended `async function execute<TItems extends WorkItems<any, any>>(workItems: TItems) {
    return Promise.all(workItems.map((workItem) => workItem.fn(workItem.param)));
}`